# library(samsort) in SICStus Prolog

Tags: sicstus-prolog

In SICStus Prolog there's [`library(samsort)`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dsamsort.html),
a library for generic sorting.

The library exports the predicates `samsort/2`, `samsort/3`, `samkeysort/2`, and others.

I can see the use of these predicates, but I'm somewhat puzzled by the name prefix **sam**.

What is "sam"? Is it some abbreviation, initialism, or acronym?

What does "sam" mean? Is there a story/history behind the name "sam"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **S**mooth **A**pplicative **M**erge sort.

Originally from the DEC-10 Prolog library, I think.

It was described in a technical report, which I cannot find, unfortunately:

O’Keefe, R.: A smooth applicative merge sort. Tech. rep., Department of Artificial Intelligence, University of Edinburgh (1982)

Comment: As a user, what can I expect from samsort? Perhaps O(N) if the input is (almost) sorted—as well as O(N log N) in the general case?